# Example 'spl-token-minter' of github.com/solana-developers failed on my localnet

Tags: anchor, spl-token, token-2022

I tried example [[spl-token-minter]](https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/blob/main/tokens/spl-token-minter/anchor/tests/test.ts) on github.com/solana-developers repo on my local net.

Run `anchor run test` got error:

- Error Number: 3009. Error Message: Program account is not executable.
- Error Number: 3007. Error Message: The given account is owned by a different program than expected

[image]

It is less likely that repo code failed to run. But I can not figure out what goes wrong on my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like from the errors that the Metaplex Metadata program is not deployed on your local validator (yet you are invoking it and using it in your program).

Are you using the same [`Anchor.toml`](https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/blob/main/tokens/spl-token-minter/anchor/Anchor.toml) from the repo?

```
[test]
startup_wait = 5000
shutdown_wait = 2000

[test.validator]
bind_address = "0.0.0.0"
url = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"
ledger = ".anchor/test-ledger"
rpc_port = 8899

[[test.validator.clone]]
address = "metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s"
```

This is basically telling the testing environment to clone the Metadata program from mainnet to your local validator when it starts up (which is necessary to test your program). Without doing this step, your program will throw because Anchor has checks verifying that `metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s` is executable code.

Here's the [Anchor Reference](https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_references/anchor-toml_reference.html#test).

Comment: Thank, I also noticed the "test.validator*" section in Anchor.toml. 
I only modified the 'spl_token_minter' to latest programID.
Without reading Anchor.toml Reference before, I took it for granted that local net will prepare all dependent programs for us.
Follow your hint, I find that the error reason was: I start 'solana-test-validator' first, then execute `anchor run test`. 
Now it success if  only start `anchor test`.
So, `anchor run test` is not the same as  `anchor test`. What's their different?
If testing on devnet, do it use these "test.validator*" conf to download program too?

Comment: You can find all anchor commands with `anchor --help`.  You can find the Anchor CLI Docs [here](https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/cli). 
You don't need to deploy the Metadata program for Devnet testing because the program is [already deployed to Devnet](https://explorer.solana.com/address/metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s?cluster=devnet).

Comment: Thanks for you help and great patients.